# Create a clone/duplicate of a repo and sync both the repos

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have following situation:

1. Work has a repo e.g. ABC
2. We have a Master branch in ABC where we FTEs push our changes to
3. Few of the contractors are not going to get access to the repo ABC
4. In order for contractors to work with repo ABC, I am thinking of creating a new repo, XYZ, which is a copy/duplicate/clone of repo ABC. Repo XYZ should always receive all the changes/commits of repo ABC.
5. Provide access to repo XYZ to contractors and allow them to push their code to repo XYZ
6. Once contractors push their changes from local, they will push it to repo XYZ - Master branch. One of the FTEs will have to review those changes and approve them and push those to XYZ - Master and ABC-Master
   Is this possible? If yes, any pointers pls?

Comment: Are you planning to just have this be a normal fork, or have divergent commit histories or different contents, or something else?

Comment: Whatever the commits are made to repo ABC should flow in repo XYZ and commits of repo XYZ should flow to repo ABC only once approved

Comment: Any thoughts please?